# Convert shiny.tag object (shiny input object) to html object or character object

Tags: r, shiny

I need to convert a shiny input object to pure HTML.

```
library(shiny)
test <- selectInput("testInput", label = "", 
     choices = c("test1", "test2", "test3"), selected = "test1")
```

In this example, `test` is a shiny.tag object.

```
class(test)

#[1] "shiny.tag"
```

I want it to be an html object, as if I had parsed it from text:

```
test2 <- HTML('<div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
         <label class="control-label" for="testInput"></label>
         <div>
         <select id="testInput"><option value="test1" selected>test1</option>
         <option value="test2">test2</option>
         <option value="test3">test3</option></select>
         <script type="application/json" data-for="testInput" data-nonempty="">{}</script>
         </div>
         </div>')

class(test2)

#[1] "html"      "character"
```

I tried doing that directly like this:

```
HTML(test)

#Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : argument is not a character vector
```

But it wants a character vector, and doesn't seem to have a method for converting shiny.tag objects to HTML.

I think it should be easy to convert the shiny input object into html, but not sure how to get at that.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: have you tried `as.character(test)`?

Comment: (hand slaps forehead)....This works! So it would be `HTML(as.character(test))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `doRenderTags` or `renderTags` from `htmltools` :

```
library(shiny)
test <- selectInput(
  inputId = "testInput", label = "", 
  choices = c("test1", "test2", "test3"), selected = "test1"
)

(html <- htmltools::doRenderTags(test))
# <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
#   <label class="control-label" for="testInput"></label>
#   <div>
#     <select id="testInput"><option value="test1" selected>test1</option>
# <option value="test2">test2</option>
# <option value="test3">test3</option></select>
#     <script type="application/json" data-for="testInput" data-nonempty="">{}</script>
#   </div>
# </div>
class(html)
# [1] "html"      "character"
```

But `renderTags` is better since it resolve dependencies (in your case on `selectize.js`) :

```
html2 <- htmltools::renderTags(test)
class(html2)
# [1] "list"
str(html2, max.level = 2)
# List of 4
#  $ head        :Classes 'html', 'character'  atomic [1:1] 
#   .. ..- attr(*, "html")= logi TRUE
#  $ singletons  : chr(0) 
#  $ dependencies:List of 1
#   ..$ :List of 10
#   .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "html_dependency"
#  $ html        :Classes 'html', 'character'  atomic [1:1] <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
#   <label class="control-label" for="testInput"></label>
#   <div>
#   | __truncated__
#   .. ..- attr(*, "html")= logi TRUE
```

You can access the raw HTML with slot `html` in the list.

Comment: This is awesome.  I noticed that the `selectize.js` wasn't applied there when I applied @Adam's solution this morning, so using `renderTags` seems a much cleaner way to go.